# Vlookup FormulaR1C1 Error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the code below.  It places the formula in the correct column, but it is overwriting B:C with B:D:D.  If I manually change it back the formula works.  Can anyone tell me what is going on with the overwrite?  I am grabbing data in the VLOOKUP from another worksheet.

```
Sub vlook()

    Dim llastrow As Long       

    With Sheets("Risk")
    llastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("D2:D" & llastrow)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC2, IAVA!B:C, 2, FALSE)"
        '.Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `FormulaR1C1` then it expects `R1C1` format. You are passing some mixed format -  `RC2, IAVA!B:C,` - the first parameter is `RC` and the second is `A1B1`. Thus, Excel and VBA produce something strange as `B:D:D`.
This is working:

```
   Sub vlook()

        Dim llastrow As Long
        With Sheets("Risk")
        llastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("D2:D" & llastrow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC2, IAVA!C[-2]:C[-1], 2, FALSE)"
            '.Value = .Value
            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: You are my savior.   Thank you!